# Quantum Mechanics Text for Electrical Engineers

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education, semiconductor-physics, electrical-engineering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a good introductory book on quantum mechanics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/33215/what-is-a-good-introductory-book-on-quantum-mechanics)

What is a good introductory text on quantum mechanics that could be used to train electrical engineers in device physics and band structure in a single semester?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33215/2451