# Quantum harmonic oscillator - book that does it all right

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, harmonic-oscillator

I am dealing with quantum harmonic oscillator.

In every single  book or video i have checked out i can read how the mathematical technique for solving this [Schrödinger equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation):

$$
W\psi = - \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{d^2 \psi}{dx^2} + \frac{1}{2}m \omega^2 x^2
$$

is beyond the level of the book/video... I really want to learn this stuff and noone seems to be able to explain it. I have dealt with tunelling, particle in a box, potential steps... **so why do authors think i can't handle this?**

**I need a good book recommendations**.

Comment: doesn't Griffiths do it quite ok?

Comment: Is there any other?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33215/2451 and links therein.

Comment: This is dangerously close to make a list/a dupe of the question @Qmechanic just provided. But I can think of at least three specific references within reach, so I might just list those.

Comment: I would highly highly recommend Cohen-Tannoudji.

Comment: This question was closed while I was typing up an answer. I have converted that answer into a proposed edit for the [tag:harmonic-oscillator] tag wiki.