# Quantum Physics Books

Tags: quantum-mechanics, soft-question, resource-recommendations, education

I`m very newbie in physics and want to study on amateur level.

I`m interested in Quantum Physics, can anybody advice some books?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of old threads here with the same question. Here's a link to an old, though closed thread with some good suggestions [What is a good introductory book on quantum mechanics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/33215/what-is-a-good-introductory-book-on-quantum-mechanics)

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with this book first and then once you understand more about Quantum Physics then I'd suggest you move onto something more advanced.

1. [Quantum Physics For Dummies](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Quantum-Physics-Dummies-Steve-Holzner/dp/1118460820/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1389002959&sr=1-1&keywords=quantum%20physics%20for%20dummies)
2. [Quantum: A Guide for The Perplexed](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Quantum-Guide-For-The-Perplexed/dp/1780223951/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1389003043&sr=8-4&keywords=quantum%20physics)

This should give you a good set of knowledge for this topic

Comment: I would rather suggest the OP to start off with Griffiths.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

I read books by John Gribbin when I was at school, certainly played a part in me studying physics. In Search of Schrödinger's Cat was my favourite but there are a couple of others.