# What is a wave? What is a particle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, particle-physics, wave-particle-duality

I am reading a David Bohm book on quantum theory. He says the idea that light is both a particle and a wave is incompatible:

(1) we know light has particle-like properties through the photoelectric effect

(2) we know light also has wave like properties because of slit experiments.

He then explains why they are incompatible.

But what is a "particle"? What is a "wave"? What do these terms mean *precisely*?  I know what they mean loosely. A particle means something occupying a spatial position. A wave is like a density or something defined with peaks, troughs, and nodes over a spatial region. But I want something more rigorous and more accurate than these loose definitions so that I know what I mean when I use the term.

I'd like the definitions stated like we state axioms in math, clearly and specifically. In math, I say a vector space is closed under addition if $x,y\in V$ implies $x+y \in V$. Those are very specific claims.

Can someone do something similarly clear and specific with wave and particle?

Comment: A lot of comments deleted. Physics SE is not a place to [fix the internet](http://xkcd.com/386/).

Comment: A "point particle" in classical mechanics is the concept that one can approximate the motion of a real, extended object by the motion of its center of mass. If you stick to this ontology, it makes no sense to say that the photoelectric effect implies particle properties. A "wave" in classical mechanics is the collective motion of a solid, liquid or gas. In classical electrodynamics it's the propagation of energy in a vacuum field. The slit experiments do not show any resemblance to that kind of wave motion because single quanta show interference effects without there being a "collective".

Comment: @CuriousOne well they do. Otherwise the term "wave-particle duality" wouldn't have appeared.

Comment: @Ruslan: The term wave-particle duality appeared because otherwise very smart people were highly confused. It's a historic artifact of that confusion, just like "aether" is the result of another. If you apply the correct classical definition of "point particle" as the approximation that neglects internal degrees of freedom and moments of inertia of the motion of extended real objects, then you can find no logical way of using it in the context of the photo effect. There are no extended objects there that need to be approximated.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46237

Comment: @CuriousOne can u elaborate on what u mean by "without there being a collective"?

Comment: Classical waves stem from phenomena that happen in well defined volumes of continuous media like water or air, a liquid that can be poured from one cup to another, a gas that can be held in a jar. These media can be divided into equally behaving parts and we have come to understand "waves" as linear displacements of these parts against the whole. These displacements can be measured continuously in the whole volume without disturbing the waves. But if we tried measuring even a small volume of the quantum system in addition to the detector, the "wave" like quality will disappear.

Comment: If the wave quality disappears, what does it become? Obviously this is Heisenberg uncertainty principle. But are you saying that an electron *is* a wave or it *moves* like a wave and is a particle? I suspect neither lol. But the diagrams anna described in her answer make it sound like the electron's trajectory is a wave rather than its localization and that it actually manifests as a particle if it ever has any definite spatial location.  In other words, a ripple in the ocean is defined as a change to the state of the media. It's not a thing. It's like phonons. But a particle could have

Comment: localization and move like a wave. I'm not trying to be difficult. I am just confused and likely unclear as a result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concepts "particle" and "wave" started from classical physics and from the everyday use of the terms, to begin with. A particle of dust got into one's eye, and the sea had huge waves.

Physics came into its reign when mathematics was seriously used to model observations.

For classical physics "particle" means an entity with small mass and a center of mass tracked at coordinates (x,y,z) at time t. Solutions of kinematic differential equations described the trajectory with accuracy determined by experimental errors.

For classical physics, waves are modeled by sinusoidal functions, i.e. functions that were the solution of "wave equations", could describe the behavior of sea waves, sound waves, and finally electromagnetic waves. Classically a wave is a variation of a measurable quantity like energy, or electric field, in space at a given time t, and the theoretical models were very successful  in describing the observations of periodic energy distributions in bulk matter, and even in empty space ( electromagnetic waves).

Then quantum mechanics became necessary, from the discreteness of atoms, the black body radiation spectrum, the photoelectric effect it was finally understood that there were regions in the variables measured that displayed a quantization of energy.

It so happens that the equations that successfully describe the quantum mechanical state of matter were diferential equations with sinusoidal solutions, i.e. wave equations, like the [Schrodinger equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation). The solutions for the hydrogen atom were able to explain the spectral series adhoc assigned by the Bohr model, IF the postulate was assumed that the wavefunction squared did not  represent the energy of the electron at (x,y,z) at time t,  *but a probability distribution.* i.e. if one accumulated with the same boundary conditions a large number of measurements and plotted the (x,y,z) at time t distributions one would know how probable it would be to find the electron at that location.

As an example, this is similar to taking a census of the population of a city by age, and gauging how probable it would be that the first person you meet will be 8 years old. The wave function's function is just that, to give probabilities mathematically which are checked experimentally, and have been very accurate.

The "wave" part  confused and continues to confuse people, because they think that the quantum mechanical entity, the electron for example, is spread out according to the solution of the Schrodinger equation. This is a misunderstanding, as the double slit interference experiments show with incoming [single electrons:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles)

[image: dbl slit single electron]

Note the top photo, where the electron impinges on the screen, it is one whole electron . The probability pattern accumulated though shows clearly the interference effect that is expected by the sinusoidal form of the wave functions describing the electron when it hits the slits and goes through one or the other.

The "particle" facet of the electron is that it appears as a point at ( x,y,z_0) of the screen, and the "wave" facet is the probability distribution displayed in its trajectories.

If one is becoming a physicist it is simple to accept this fact, that the microcosm behaves differently than the macroscopic world we are used to. Bohm was stuck on classical frameworks and tried to derive the quantum mechanical probabilities from an underlying classical description. He succeeded in reproducing the same results as the usual quantum mechanical solutions, but afaik his model is complicated  and limited, and cannot be extended into second quantization where the ball game has gone  now.

Comment: Is Bohm out of date? I am wary of reading people with views that aren't current enough or not mainstream enough. Would you suggest I read someone else to learn more about quantum theory? If so, any recommendations?

Comment: Yes ,  Bohm is both out of date and not mainstream, although I believe there exist people carrying on those lines of research. For mainstream  try the recommendations on this site http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/33215/what-is-a-good-introductory-book-on-quantum-mechanics

Comment: @annav : that's not true, no, not at all. Bohm's interpretation is considered a courageous trial to get rid of the "collapse" postulate. If this trial is good, that's another question. There are serious researchers ready to admit that there exists, in the microscopic world, a preferred frame. I had long talks with such people. And there were experiments (Gisin's group) trying to find whether a preferred frame can exist for quantum particles. But the experiments were non-conclusive. Thus, as far as we can't disprove the existence of a preferred frame, we can't rule out Bohm's interpretation.

Comment: @Sofia I am saying that it is not main stream, and also mentioning that there are people still working on it. From the various ways one can expand even a simple mathematical function, it is always possible to have much more complicated ways of arriving to the same prediction. There is no reason to adopt the most complicated path and a lot of reasons to keep the simpler one.

Comment: @annav, let me tell you from my contacts. Nobody likes the collapse. The people are not ready to accept it. It's not mathematics here, it's physics. The QM is unable to explain the measurement. QM is not a complete theory, as simple as that, it needs something from outside, and that something is not at all understood. About Bohm's interpretation, it is not a more complicated way. Its mathematics is simple, plausible, many people believe in it. And it is a very well developed mathematics, there are many books on it. Unfortunately, it is at odds with the relativity.

Comment: @Sofia that it is at odds with relativity makes it useless for describing all the existing data in high energies. It then becomes mathematics and science fiction. Physics is not about consensus or acceptance. I do not use collapse as a term, no more than I would use it for classical probabilities. Quantum mechanics explains up to now the data from the microscosm , it is not broken to be fixed unless a disagreement with data appears. Not "likings" and "not-likings" of mathematics by people.

Comment: @annav , hi! I am no supporter of Bohm's mechanics (BM). BM has additional problems of being unfit for describing photons. Now, the fact that you don't use the term "collapse" it's personal matter. The quantum community **has** the problem of the collapse. Also, in high energies' physics you don't compare predictions of two observers travelling in opposite directions, do you? This comparison is BM's problem with the relativity. As one that searched quite deeply the BM, I can say that it's not science fiction. My feeling is that the truth is somewhere between BM and QM, but we can't say where.

Comment: @Sofia  We have elementary particles interacting and going with very high energies in different directions. Human observers rushing around close to the speed of light are an intellectual game in my books, not an experimentally verifiable situation.

Comment: @annav : we came to a point at which each one of us understands what the other one speaks. I hope to God that we can check the BM, even without moving frames. As I see from my talks with acquaintances, people are in general ready to close their eyes at the difficulties with the photons hoping for future solutions. But if, as I am afraid, my investigation results will be negative, i.e. BM wrong, it would be a blow on us. It's hard to accept to remain with the collapse, which our mind doesn't understand. And again, avoiding the word, won't help. Well, bed-time. Pleasant dreams!

Comment: @annav : I apologize for disturbing. I felt the need to add a few more words. You see, it's not BM here under question mark. It's **the human mind**. Are we, or aren't we, able to understand the nature? My teacher and friend doubts the power of the human mind. I can't accept such a thing. If our mind is not able to understand the nature, then beyond the corner waits for us the darkness, the mysticism. Well, again, good night!

Comment: @Sofia When I throw dice, and 4 comes on the face, I do not say that there was a collapse of the probability at 4. Probability is just a distribution, one throw is an instance in the distribution.  What is not to understand in that? my bedtime too. good night

Comment: Please clarify the paragraph above the last, Do you mean that the particle is what you observe on the screen when an electron stuck on it and Wave is what appears when a whole set of electron strick to the wall? There is no wave associated with particle but to set of particles. Is this what you are saying?

Comment: @annav Make above clear.

Comment: @YoungKindaichi  A particle exists in indivifual interactions, as can be seen in the points in the frames above. Each point is  afootprint  of an interaction with the double slits. Electrons are quantum mechanical entities, and quantum mechanics can predict only  .  a probability distribution, and  needs a nunber of particles with the same boundary conditions measured the same way ( with the points on the screen). It is the probability distribytion given by the complex conjugate square of the wavefunction($Ψ$)  $Ψ^*Ψ$ that shows interference effects.

Comment: @annav so here there's no wave, after all, just a particle and a probability distribution.

Comment: Any chance that the existence of "particle" is just an illusion - a manifestation of a wave? i.e. waves have discrete properties, like wave numbers, which might manifest as particles. The double-slit experiment: all we really know is that the energy of the entity was deposited at a particular location - not that the entity *is* a particle. Is it possible to interpret correctly a particle as a manifestation of a wave? i.e. Wave energy wrapped upon itself?

Comment: Not in manstream quantum mechanics theories. Various theories exist trying to determne the probability distributions from underlying deterministic levels.see  posts by 't https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/11205/g-t-hooftHooft's here on this site

Answer (score 0):

A particle is simply a piece of matter.

A wave is a type of oscillatory motion (vibrating up and down in crests and troughs).

Not too long ago in the history of science, scientists used to think that a moving particle moves in strictly straight line (provided that no other force is acting on it). They also used to think that electromagnetic radiation do not contain any matter and are just an expression of energy. Planck then gave his famous law that every moving object in fact moves as a wave (with oscillations) and not exactly a straight line. The heavier the object, the lesser the oscillation (and greater the wavelength). Electromagnetic radiation are in fact extremely light particles (called photons) which travel through space in oscillatory motion.

Answer (score -1):

A particle is the smallest vibration of a quantum field.A wave is like a density or something defined with peaks, troughs, and nodes over a spatial region.