# What is wave? Difference between particle and wave

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, waves, wave-particle-duality

What is wave? We simply define particle nature. When we draw a graph representing a wave then we show a graph between position of particle and time. Then how do we distinguish between a particle and a wave?

Comment: A wave is a _mathematical model_ of a disturbance that propagates through a medium.  It (i.e., the _model_) is useful for describing some familiar things like sound propagating through air and ripples propagating across the surface of a pond.  It also turns out to be useful for describing things in quantum physics.  I am not a physicist, so I don't know what meaning physicists ascribe to the "waveness" of quantum things.

Comment: A wave is an expression, an indication of the flow of energy through space and time.

Comment: "When we draw a graph representing a wave then we show a graph between position of particle and time"? No we don't. Water waves are not graphs of any trajectories, they are  all there in a snapshot (same with elastic, electromagnetic, etc., waves). Waves are spread out, particles are localized, wave motion accomplishes spatial energy transfer with almost no (traditional) mass transfer, particle motion is all in mass transfer, see [waves in physics on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave).

Comment: The wave graph often isn't position against time; it's normally an amplitude against location (or momentum, or whichever continuous observable you're working with).

Comment: You cannot physically describe an electromagnetic wave without photons. A good analogy of photons would be individual marching soldiers. Coherent photons would be like waves of marching soldiers in perfect order.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a wave? What is a particle?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/155981/what-is-a-wave-what-is-a-particle)

Answer (score 2):

A way to distinguish a wave from a particle is simply observing how they interact in certain experiments.  For example, a photon exhibits attributes of both a particle and a wave so we can observe behaviors of both a particle and a wave through photons.  In some experiments light will refract which is a behavior specific to a wave whereas in others a photon will transfer energy to an electron which is a behavior specific to a particle.

In specifically defining a wave it is necessary for something to oscillate, whether this is physical motion or energy fluctuations is irrelevant, and to therefore possess amplitude.  A key factor of waves is that amplitudes can add or subtract from one another so in experiments such as the [Double-slit experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment) the amplitudes can be seen canceling out showing the wave nature of the photon.

Comment: With each photon having its own oscillating amplitude you can explain every phenomena of light. Billions of individual photons form a wave.