# Which one is good for starters in QM? Principles of Quantum mechanics by Dirac or by Shankar?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

I've learnt a bit of linear algebra and both single variable and multivariable calculus.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a good introductory book on quantum mechanics?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33215/)

Answer (score 1):

The best book about QM for beginners I know is by the Nobel Prize Claude Cohen-Tannoudji, coauthored with Bernard Diu and Frank Laloë. Mécanique quantique. 2 cols. Collection Enseignement des Sciences. Paris. (Quantum Mechanics. Vol. I & II, 1991. Wiley, New-York).

Even I could understand it.