# Which is a good and short book for foundations of quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-states

I am looking for a book that has stuff on quantum states, entanglement, etc.
I am aware of the book, *Geometry of Quantum States*.

I have read Ballentine's book, *Quantum Mechanics: A modern development*

Comment: Lectures on Quantum Theory: Mathematical and Structural Foundations by Chris Isham is great. Presents many of the modern issues with QM, and teaches interesting mathematics not presented in most books.

Comment: Duplicate of [What is a good introductory book on quantum mechanics?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33215/50583). If you do not mean "introductory" with "foundations", please rephrase the question and elaborate what you are seeking.

Comment: If the OP has read Ballentine I doubt that they are looking for an intro text @ACuriousMind

Comment: Usually the more modern developments (like POVM, entanglement) are treated in quantum information. Although finding a good book on QI is hard. Did you have a look at Nielsen and Chuang? (If these are the topics which interest you, I find the presentation very unpalatable;  but thats probably just me)

Comment: I read the following: Nielsen and Chuang, Operational Quantum Physics by Busch et.al, Quantum theoryof measurement by Busch, et.al, States, effects and operations by Krauss, A Peres' book and Isham's book. They are all good. Nielsen and Chuang seems basic and does not motivate most of the stuff it's more like a textbook for quantum information people.