# Alternatives to the Feynman Lectures

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations

I wanted to get a grounding in quantum mechanics, and was directed to the Feynman lectures. I was told to start from Vol I and work my way up to Vol III, where all the quantum mechanics stuff is. As a mathematician, I figured that the subject shouldn't be too difficult.

However, the books are far too broad, and full of stuff that was covered in my High School physics classes. I've also heard that the section on quantum mechanics doesn't really go into much depth.

My question is what should I read to gain a solid and deep understanding (as deep an understanding one can get without a physics degree) of quantum mechanics. Certain chapters of the Feynman lectures? A different book entirely?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of [What is a good introductory book on quantum mechanics?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33215/50583)