# Gradient of a wave function, notational confusion

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, hilbert-space, notation, differentiation

I'm reading from "Quantum Physics for Dummies", by Steven Holzner. In chapter two, entitled "Entering the Matrix: Welcome to State Vectors", the author introduces the notation for a gradient of a wave function.

[image: Gradient operator]

I understand all of the complement, but what confuses me is the use of the relationship operators, what do they signify in this context? How can you compare a partial derivative with a basis vector?

Comment: Having seen only these few lines I would definitely recommend to get the basics from some other book. Gradients of state vectors are a gross abuse of notation.

Comment: @noah would you have any recommendations?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, no. But I'm sure you can find some at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/33215/what-is-a-good-introductory-book-on-quantum-mechanics. I just felt the need to mention that this is not a quality source.

Comment: Throw the book away.

Answer (score 6):

This is typeset terribly. What it is supposed to mean is ket-vectors in [Dirac notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_notation), which are usually set with an "rangle" ($\rangle$) and "langle" ($\langle$), not > and <.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the author misuses the [bra-ket notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation). A state should be written in the form

$$
| \phi \rangle
$$

instead of $|\phi >$. This way, the gradient should appear as

$$
\nabla |\psi\rangle = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}|\psi\rangle {\bf i} + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}|\psi\rangle {\bf j} + \frac{\partial}{\partial z}|\psi\rangle {\bf k} 
$$

Comment: I think we can assume that was more related to the publisher than the author, but that really doesn't help me

Comment: Oh my god. I'm a moron. 