# Book suggestion for quantum mechanics for a noob

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

I am a high schooler who's really interested in quantum mechanics. I just need a few suggestions as to the books I can refer to to give me an idea about the equations and theories about quantum mechanics.

I understand that this is a stupid question to ask on aplatform where everyone who has something to say generally literally has a phd in that subject but any guidance as to how to go about it would really help.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! As an FYI, [this page](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4698/87049) on this site's policy for resource recommendation questions may be of interest in helping you refine the question (and for potential answer authors).  For example, it might be helpful to know more about your background in math skills.

Comment: Let me shatter your illusions : no PhD required, not even a BSc or a BA.  Just a willingness to learn and to make an effort to solve your own problems.  The main thing we discourage is do-my-homework type questions and non-mainstream physics (and personal theories).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a good introductory book on quantum mechanics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33215/)