# What are some recommended textbooks for Quantum Mechanics and General Relativity for someone with a math (but no physics) background?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, resource-recommendations, education

As the title suggests, I have a math background that includes a math major and coursework most notably in linear algebra, analysis, abstract algebra, topology, and some measure theory as well as a course of ODE/PDEs, probability, and mathematical stats. But, I do not have any background in physics beyond HS physics. What are some recommended textbooks to learn Quantum Mechanics and General Relativity? Is studying classical physics necessary to read textbooks on these topics?

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/363/, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33215/

Comment: Barret O'Neil's Semi-reimannian geometry book is also an introduction to general relativity, and is heavily math-focused.  Wald's book is probably another place that would be more appropriate if you have a heavier math background.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a 2nd year bachelor in mechanical engineering and also greatly interested in physics. Since I also do not have a real physics background I can somewhat relate to your question. I started with Griffiths Quantum Mechanics. This is an excellent book and nearly no physics background is needed. Concepts are well explained and build from the ground up. The hard part for me was sometimes the mathematics behind it but this should not be a problem for you.

As for General relativity Sean Carrols book, an introduction to General Relativity, is a good one. General relativity has a deep mathematical nature and is build up from differential geometry and tensor calculus. The physics that is build into the theory is especially for an introductionary course easy to follow or to teach yourself.

Hope this helps you a bit.