# What are the best quantum mechanic books that focus on the Dirac notation and linear algebra?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, resource-recommendations, notation, mathematics

I have a little bit of a hard time following the Dirac notation and the mathematics that follow it. Are there any textbooks that focus on the math only?

Comment: Try, Quantum Mechanics, Vol. 1 by Claude Cohen-Tannoudji, Bernard Diu, Frank Laloe

Comment: Dirac's textbook!

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33215/2451 and links therein.