# Question about the operators in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, resource-recommendations, linear-algebra

I am confused about the operators in quantum mechanics and even the way they are used, their symbols, etc. Is there any book or anything that I can study so that I can fully understand them before continuing into quantum mechanics? (I am not sure  if this forum is appropriate for questions like this so if it is not I am willing to delete my question)

Comment: You can always start by reading about operators from a functional analysis perspective, but if you are struggling now functional analysis will set you back.  Best bet is a *good* text on quantum mechanics.  Which one are you using now?

Comment: Griffiths introduction to quantum mechanics

Comment: The standard texts that should teach you about those are...textbooks about quantum mechanics. I'm confused about this idea to learn about operators "before continuing into quantum mechanics" - can you be more specific what you're looking for or what is confusing you? Do you want a more mathematical perspective? Or, on the other extreme, are you lacking the mathematical prerequisites from linear algebra many texts presuppose? Something else?

Comment: can you clarify then what you are confused about?

Comment: He makes a very small reference to operators but I think it is inadequate since he probably considers that the reader knows  a couple of things about them

Comment: The formal way of learning about operators is to study linear algebra?

Comment: Try “Linear operators for quantum mechanics” by Thomas F. Jordan or “Quantum mechanics in simple matrix form” by the same author.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero thank you very much!

Comment: As a mathematician interested in the interactions of math and physics (and number theory), I'd recommend _not_ going down a formal road of studying "operator theory", since this is a thing that has taken on a life of its own, and is not particularly friendly to physics. Instead, at your leisure, "back-fill" the mathematical operator theory that gives rigor to the physics computations that you _have_ to do, and _know_ how to do, even if you can't justify them. :) And distribution theory, etc...

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33215/2451 and links therein.