# Recommended books for Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

I am taking an introductory course in Quantum Mechanics(which starts next month)I have been studying Quantum Mechanics a little just out of curiosity, Traditionally, the required textbook used to be the book by DJ Griffiths and Eisberg and Resnick, but, since last year there has been a change, the professor who took the course last year (and also is supposed to take the course this year). Asked students to either refer to Shankar's book or the book by Leonard Schiff. I therefore request for your advice on which book should I go for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a good introductory book on quantum mechanics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33215/)

Comment: Yes,thank you sir