# Quantum Mechanics course supplement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

Does anyone have suggestions for a good quantum book to act as a supplement to the textbook? Think something like a "Quantum Mechanics for Dummies". More conceptual than rigorous, but enough math so that it will actually be useful. Maybe some practice problems. The course is an undergraduate quantum 1 course, by the way.

Comment: What textbook does your course use?

Comment: Undergrad courses are all "QM for dummies". You won't get away with much less than what your introductory textbooks contain. The only serious "mistakes" that your textbooks make are ontological. You will have to live with that because there is probably not a single author out there who wants to break with a century of bad habits of teaching using the word "particle". Think "quantum" every time the book says "particle" and you will be alright. A "quantum" is an irreversible energy exchange between a quantum system and an external "measurement system", just like in the photoelectric effect.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33215/2451 and links therein.